# Изменение php переменной через js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть php переменная. Есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую значение этой переменной должно меняться. Происходить это должно через js. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей вам нужно использовать [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) или можно использовать GET параметры.

По кнопке вызвать Ajax метод,  в котором вы напишите запрос на изменение переменной.

В php коде примите эти изменения и подставьте туда куда вам нужно.

Если переменная негде не хранится, значение всегда будет сбрасываться.